# Taking up CSV on a data frame . Using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have to read a file which is in the HDFS and convert it to a data frame . I am doing the below steps. But unable to go ahead. Need some help.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
stock1 = spark.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/stockdata/companylist_noheader.csv")
```

When I do so I get the below output

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uOyh.png)

But the actual csv file is like below 
[The input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQXYo.png)

Please suggest. I know we have a | delimited but when I use a map function I get the below error 
attributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

Comment: you need to specify the delimiter while reading. `sep='|'`. Please read the docs.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for your replies . I was able to achieve this by doing the below

Comment: stock2 = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").csv("/FileStore/tables/stockdata/companylist_noheader.csv")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you get your `DataFrame`  convert in to `RDD` and then use map transformation.

You can't map a `DataFrame`, but you can convert the `DataFrame` to an RDD . map that by doing `yourdf.rdd.map(....)`

that's the reason you are encountering

```
attributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```